# Find which extension is slowing vim

Tags: vim

my vim takes a lot of time to startup due to some extension, but I'm not sure which.
How can I find which extension is slowing vim and get rid of it?

Comment: Ah ok, that pretty much answers my question.

Comment: Generic tip for debugging extensions (learned in my Mac OS 7 days): use binary debugging. 1. Disable the top half of your extensions. 2. If the problem persist it is most likely caused by the enabled half so disable its top half. 3. Do that again until you find the culprit. It is very easy and fast.